# writing a file in Java without O_SYNC semantics

Tags: java, io, nio, nio2

In C, when I call `open()` to open a file descriptor, I have to explicitly pass the `O_SYNC` flag to ensure that writes to this file will be persisted to disk by the time `write()` returns. If I want to, I can *not* supply `O_SYNC` to `open()`, and then my writes will return much more quickly because they only have to make it into a filesystem cache before returning. If I want to, later on I can force all outstanding writes to this file to be written to disk by calling `fsync()`, which blocks until that operation has finished. (More details are available on all this in the [Linux man page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/open.2.html).)

Is there any way to do this in Java? The most similar thing I could find was using a `BufferedOutputStream` and calling `.flush()` on it, but if I'm doing writes to randomized file offsets I believe this would mean the internal buffer for the output stream could end up consuming a lot of memory.

Comment: If you're doing writes to random offsets you can't use `BufferedOutputStream` anyway because it's sequential. You'll have to use something like `RandomAccessFile`, but then I don't know how to control its buffering (if there's any at all). You may wish to look at `SeekableByteChannel` created with [Files.newByteChannel](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#newByteChannel-java.nio.file.Path-java.util.Set-java.nio.file.attribute.FileAttribute...-), but I haven't used it so I can't provide a detailed answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on Sergey Tachenov's comment, I found that you can use `FileChannel` for this. Here's some sample code that I think does the trick:

```
import java.nio.*;
import java.nio.channels.*;
import java.nio.file.*;
import java.nio.file.attribute.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.util.concurrent.*;

import static java.nio.file.StandardOpenOption.*;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        // Open the file as a FileChannel.
        Set<OpenOption> options = new HashSet<>();
        options.add(WRITE);
        // options.add(SYNC);     <------- This would force O_SYNC semantics.
        try (FileChannel channel = FileChannel.open(Paths.get("./test.txt"), options)) {

            // Generate a bit data to write.
            ByteBuffer buffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(4096);
            for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
                buffer.put(i, (byte) i);
            }

            // Choose a random offset between 0 and 1023 and write to it.
            long offset = ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextLong(0, 1024);
            channel.write(buffer, offset);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Using Java 7 NIO [FileChannel](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/channels/FileChannel.html)#[force](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/channels/FileChannel.html#force(boolean)) method:

```
RandomAccessFile aFile = new RandomAccessFile("file.txt", "rw");
FileChannel inChannel = aFile.getChannel();
// .....................
// flushes all unwritten data from the channel to the disk
channel.force(true);
```

An important detail :

> If the file does not reside on a local device then no such guarantee is made.